# Electron prevent opening same window multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am developing an Electron application which includes a few seperate windows. I am using a button click event to open new window and call `window.open` method. Problem is, if I click the button more than once, everytime same window opens. I want to prevent to open same window more than once.

This is the click event call.

```js
window.open('settings.html', '_blank');
```

And this is configuration for `settings.html` page.

```js
mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(({ url }) => {
  if (path.basename(url) === 'settings.html') {
    return {
      action: 'allow',
      overrideBrowserWindowOptions: {
        width: 400,
        height: 450,
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
        fullscreenable: false,
        webPreferences: {
          preload: path.join(__dirname, 'js', 'preload.js')
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return { action: 'deny' }
});
```

Configurations currently locating in `createWindow()` function.

*Electron version is 24.4*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try to handle that with ipc. call `ipcRenderer.invoke("open-window", url)` in renderer and `ipcMain.handle("open-window", (event, url) => {...})` in main. In main you have `const browserWindows = []` where you store the browserWindows you have opened so far. In `ipcMain.handle()` you check the `browserWindows` array if that browser window is already open, if yes: dont open another one. If no: open a new one with `new BrowserWindow(...)` and add it to the `browserWindows` array. Make the renderer click handler async, so that you can do something like that to prevent multiple clicks while ipcMain still need to handle your open request (but maybe that is not necessary):

```js
async onClick() {
  buttonDisabled = true;
  await ipcRenderer.invoke("open-window", url);
  buttonDisabled = false;
}
```

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc

you probably need some additional logic to remove browserWindows when they are closed from the `browserWindows` array.

Or maybe you can do all of that in the `setWindowOpenHandler` too instead of using ipc. You could create a windowUrls array for example and check that instead of a browserWindows array.

Comment: I ended up with modal window configuration. Your answer led me to right path. [Modal windows](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#modal-windows)

Comment: yeah, in most cases that is probably better than opening up multiple windows